# Apache to nginx migration: friendly urls. Rewrite and post data

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, rewrite

I am migrating a little API from apache to nginx and I have changed the htaccess file to location rules in nginx config file.

I have a POST request that is loosing the post data.

This is the htaccess:

```
Rewriterule ^users/register /users.php [NS]
```

And this is the nginx rule:

```
location /users {
    rewrite ^/users/register /users.php;
}
```

The point is that the redirection is working fine but if I do a print_r($_SERVER), I can see a GET request instead of POST, and there is no POST value.

What am I doing wrong?
I am new with nginx, is there any other way to configure friendly urls?

Comment: `nginx` doesn't alter GET to POST (and vice versa) in any way, so if you are seeing not what you expected to see, `nginx` or `.htaccess` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
rewrite ^/users/register$ /users.php
```

Comment: Putting dollar sign at the end of request URL always worked for me.